# TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'. in pandas with Groupby or PivotTable

Tags: python, pandas, syntax-error, typeerror

first at all I want to specify that my question is very similar to others questions done before, but I tried their answers and nothing worked for me.

I'm trying to aggregate some info using more than one variable to group. I can use pivot table or groupby, both are fine for this, but I get the same error all the time.

My code is:

```
import numpy as np
vars_agrup = ['num_vars', 'list_vars', 'Modelo']
metricas =  ["MAE", "MAE_perc", "MSE", "R2"]
g = pd.pivot_table(df, index=vars_agrup,  aggfunc=np.sum, values=metricas)
```

or

```
df.groupby(vars_agrup, as_index=False).agg(Count=('MAE','sum'))
```

Also, I tried to use () instead of [] to avoid make it a list, but then the program search a column called "'num_vars', 'list_vars', 'Modelo'" which doesn't exist. I tried ([]) and [()]. Index instead of columns. It's always the same: for one variable to group it's fine, for multiples I get the error: `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`

For sure, all these variables are columns in `df`.

Edit: My df looks like this:
[image]

Comment: "but I tried their answers and nothing worked for me." Which questions did you find? What answers did you try? What *specific changes to the code did you make* in order to try them? What happened as a result?

Comment: Please share how `df` looks like. Otherwise we can't understand or replicate the issue.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel what I tried It's what I explained: using tuples, tuples in list, list in tuples. And also, I used columns instead of index.